# ORA-00904: "cadete": invalid identifier in a check

Tags: sql, oracle

why do I get ORA-00904: "cadete": invalid identifier? I have noticed I dont get this when I put a number in the check

```
create table empleado
(DNI number(10) primary key,
nombre varchar(100),
apellido varchar(100),
email varchar(100),
celular varchar(100),
posicion varchar(100),
constraint ch_posicion
check(posicion IN ("administrativo","cadete")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need only single quotes around values instead of double quotes -

```
create table empleado
(DNI number(10) primary key,
nombre varchar(100),
apellido varchar(100),
email varchar(100),
celular varchar(100),
posicion varchar(100),
constraint ch_posicion
check(posicion IN ('administrativo','cadete')))
```

Comment: No "probably" about it!  :-)  Also, while not part of the problem, the OP should be using VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR.

Comment: And also, for the OP's benefit, the reason the solution by @Ankit Bajpai is correct is that double quotes are used to indicate a an object name (and a _case-sensitive_ one, at that)... like a table or column name.  That not what is called for in an IN-list.  Single quotes are used to indicate a character string.